# Assigning Mysql Row Value To another Query in a Same PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to assign a query table value to another query in a same php file. For an example `$pin_Value` this value will be used for my second query in the page. This variable will be used in html too..

how to assign `$pin_Value` value to my second query?

kindly see the comment code for further info.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include('config.php');
    $table_content = "";
    $table_content2 = "";
    $pin_Value = "";
    $po_Value = "";
    $dist_Value = "";
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM pincode_data where poName='" . $_GET['po']."' ORDER BY postalDivision ASC";
    $pind = mysql_fetch_array($pinCode);
    $result = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $pin_Value = $row['pinCode'];
            $po_Value = $row['postOffice'];
            $dist_Value = $row['districtName'];
            $state_Value = $row['stateName'];
            $table_content .= "<tr><td>Pincode:</td><td><a href='pinview.php?pin=" . $row['pinCode'] . "'>".$row['pinCode'] . "</a></td></tr>";
            $table_content .= "<tr><td>Office Name:</td><td><a href='poview.php?po=" . $row['postOffice'] . "'>".$row['postOffice'] . "</a></td></tr>"; 
            $table_content .= "<tr><td>District:</td><td><a href='../district.php?dist=" .$row[districtName] . "'> ".$row['districtName'] . " </a></td></tr>";
        } 
            mysql_close();
            $pin_Value = $row['pinCode']; // this value to be assigned to another query

    $qry2 = "SELECT DISTINCT postOffice FROM pincode_data WHERE pinCode ='" . $pin_Value . "'"; // here is the issue
    $result2 = mysql_query($qry2);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $table_content2 .= "<li><a href='districtview.php?dist=".$row['postOffice']."'> ".$row['postOffice']."</a></li>";
        }

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What is happening or not happening with what you have?

Comment: @Rasclatt : I got $row['pinCode'] value from my first query.

I would like to use $row['pinCode'] this value to my second query in the same page. 


how to assin $row['pinCode'] value to following query


$qry2 = "SELECT DISTINCT postOffice FROM pincode_data WHERE pinCode ='" . $row['pinCode'] . "'";

Comment: You are already assigning it to the 2nd Query? So what is the actual problem?

Comment: @phpphil: I have assigned but the query doesnt show any result.

Comment: See @user1374650 answer - it's possible you are not using the pinCode from the correct row. In your query you will always use the pinCode of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your 1st query there may be more than one result for $row['pinCode'] so the best practice is that try to make an array suppose $pincode and store all values in $pincode array inside while loop then try to use forach loop for $pincode and inside foreach loop use your query or in second query try to use  ( IN ) Clause in your query.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
$pin_Value = $row['pinCode'];
```

after

```
mysql_close();
```

You have already define $pin_value inside while loop.